# Mysqli returning error "Commands out of sync" when trying to do multiple prepared statements

Tags: php, sql, arrays, mysqli, prepared-statement

I get an error 'Call to a member function bind_param() ' on  $noofspellschamps->bind_param('ss', $Patch_No, $champion); I've tested few things and it's not the problem with Prepare since it works fine on phpmyadmin, I assume the problem is with executions or possibly I need to close first the stream from $champions but I need them both as you can see in the loop I'm not really sure what to do.

**EDIT2** Is there possibly anyone who knows what the problems is and could help?

```
 $i=1;
                $champion = array();
                $noofspellschamp = array();

                $Patch_No = trim($_GET['Patch_No']);

                $champions = $conn->prepare("SELECT champion FROM champions where Patch_No = ?");
                $champions->bind_param('s', $Patch_No);
                $champions->execute();
                //$champions->close();

                $champions->bind_result($champ);



                    while($champions->fetch()){

                        $champion[$i]=$champ;    

                        $noofspellschamps =$conn->prepare(
                        "SELECT Passive, Q, W, E, R,
                                ((Passive != '') + (Q != '') + (W != '') + (E != '') + (R != '')
                                ) as NumNotNull
                        FROM champions
                        WHERE Patch_No = ? AND Champion = ?");
                        $noofspellschamps->bind_param('ss', $Patch_No, $champion);
                        $noofspellschamps->execute();
                        $noofspellschamps->bind_result($noofspellsch);



                        while($noofspellschamps->fetch()){
                            $noofspellschamp[$i] = $noofspellsch['NumNotNull'];
                            echo $noofspellschamp[$i];
                        }
                        $i+=1;
                    }
```

Comment: helpful: `$result = $noofspellschamps->bind_param('ss, $Patch_No, $champion); if($result === false) echo $conn->error;` Check your returns for `false` and use the mysqli error functions to help determine the problem.

Comment: Check similarly for errors on every prepare and bind call. There's an error message in there somewhere telling you if it's a sql syntax problem, an issue with your parameter, etc.

Comment: Tried that no luck whatsoever

Comment: please post the entire error message just as it appears. Did you check the value of `$noofspellchamps` just before calling `bind_param` on it?

Comment: Fatal error: Call to a member function bind_param() on a non-object in C:\wamp\www\leaguenotes2.0\index.php on line 54  also tried echoing $noofspellschamps and doing the $result = ... and then $conn->error;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT 2**

The reason why you're getting "Commands out of sync error" is because the mysql client doesn't allow you to a new query / sub query when there are still rows being fetched from a previous in-progress query. [Commands out of sync](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/commands-out-of-sync.html)

Using example provided. (Might have to change it to your liking)

```
$i=1;
$champion = array();
$noofspellschamp = array();

$Patch_No = trim($_GET['Patch_No']);

// query 1
$champions = $conn->prepare("SELECT champion FROM champions where Patch_No = ?");
$champions->bind_param('s', $Patch_No);
$champions->execute();
$result = $champions->get_result();


while($data = $result->fetch_assoc()){

    // use data variable as an associative array

    //query 2
    $noofspellschamps = $conn->prepare(
    "SELECT Passive, Q, W, E, R,
            ((Passive != '') + (Q != '') + (W != '') + (E != '') + (R != '')
            ) as NumNotNull
    FROM champions
    WHERE Patch_No = ? AND Champion = ?");

    $noofspellschamps->bind_param('ss', $Patch_No, $data["champion"]);
    $noofspellschamps->execute();
    $result2 = $champions->get_result();



    while($data2 = $result2->fetch_assoc()){
        // other stuff with data2 variable
    }

    $i++;
}
```

As of PHP 5.3 `mysqli_stmt::get_result` which returns a result-set object. You can use `mysqli_result::fetch_array()` or `mysqli_result::fetch_assoc()`. However, note that this only available with the native MySQL driver though.

In essence:

```
$stmt = $con->prepare("SELECT id FROM table1"); // first prepared statement
$stmt->execute(); 
$result = $stmt->get_result(); // Gets a result set from a prepared statement
while($data = $result->fetch_assoc()) {  
    // do stuff with first set of data

    $stmt2 = $con->prepare("SELECT * from table2 WHERE id = ?"); // second prepared statement
    $stmt2->bind_param('s', $data["id"]);
    $stmt2->execute(); // execute second statement
    $result2 = $stmt2->get_result();
    while($data2 = $result2->fetch_assoc()) { 

        // do stuff with second set of data
    }

}
```

Comment: forgot to edit did actually the same thing like half an hour ago and the same error this is killing me

Comment: Try doing a var_dump / print_r  on your object and see what it gives you.

Comment: What about your $noofspellschamps variable. You should be getting a type object.

Comment: from var_dump($noofspellschamps) i got boolean false

Comment: If your prepared statement returns a false value boolean, it means an error occurred. Otherwise it should return a statement object. Try outputting the error `$conn->error`.

Comment: Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now. That's what I get from outputting error it's mysqli so probably I have somehow to use store_results from what I've read

Comment: That means that you're still fetching rows from the previous statement while trying to execute a new query. Take a look here: [Documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/commands-out-of-sync.html). Use mysqli_result::fetch_all() which returns the full result set as a PHP array (store it somewhere), and then you can loop over that array and call your new statement.

Comment: I still don't really get it so I need a lot more loops? once to just save it to array and then to do the second prepared statement

Comment: It means just store the result from the first using `fetch_all` and the do a while loop that contains your next prepared statement along with your new query `$noofspellschamps`. You can use `mysqli_store_result()` to pre-fetch all the rows from the outer query (`$champions`).

Comment: I can't really get fetch_all to work it's from older PHP versions I believe

Comment: Let me take a further look. I'll get back to you when I get a chance to try this out.

Comment: By the way, what version of php are you running?

Comment: the newest wamp so 5.5

Comment: @higeat Try using my second edit and let me know if it works for you. I tried it on my side and it does.